# Group by on 3 tables using a join

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have three tables
parent table: I_MOBILE_USERS

- IMU_ID (PK)
- IMU_NAME
- IMU_SURNAME
- IMU_CELL_NO
- and more but they are not needed for the query

Child table 1: I_MOBILE_USER_LOCATIONS

- IMUS_ID (PK)
- IMU_ID(FK REFERENCING PARENT TABLE PK)
- IMUS_LATITUDE (Updates every 5 min saving the persons location)
- IMUS_LONGITUDE (Updates every 5 min saving the persons location)
- DATE_CREATED (DEFAULT SYSDATE the date and time of the location log)

Child table 2: I_MOBILE_USER_SOS

- IMUS_ID (PK)
- IMU_ID (FK REFERENCING PARENT TABLE PK)
- IMU_DATE_SOS_CREATED (DEFAULT SYSDATE the date and time the sos was triggered)
- IMU_DATE_SOS_CLEARED (DISPLAYS THE DATE AND TIME THE SOS WAS CLEARED)

I need a query that would pull the name, surname, cell no and newest record of the persons location but only when the DATE_SOS_CLEARED column is empty and that one should also just get the last sos called by the person

This is what I've tried so far

```
SELECT  I_MOBILE_USERS.IMU_NAME,
        I_MOBILE_USERS.IMU_SURNAME,
        I_MOBILE_USERS.IMU_CELL_NO,
        I_MOBILE_USER_LOCATIONS.IMUL_LATITUDE,
        I_MOBILE_USER_LOCATIONS.IMUL_LONGITUDE,
        I_MOBILE_USER_SOS.IMUS_ID
        FROM I_MOBILE_USERS
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_MOBILE_USER_LOCATIONS
        ON I_MOBILE_USERS.IMU_ID = I_MOBILE_USER_LOCATIONS.IMU_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_MOBILE_USER_SOS 
        ON I_MOBILE_USERS.IMU_ID = I_MOBILE_USER_SOS.IMU_ID
        where I_MOBILE_USER_SOS.IMU_DATE_SOS CLEARED
```

That does not work because it shows all the records.
here is an example of my records:

IMU_ID, IMU_NAME, IMU_SURNAME, IMU_CELL_NO

1     , Devin   , Gericke    , 0123456789

2     , Jan     , Koen       , 0124356789

3     , Pieter  , Du plooy   , 0125346789

IMUL_ID, IMU_ID, IMUL_LATITUDE, IMUL_LONGITUDE

1      , 1     , -26.151674   ,  28.1688

2      , 1     , -26.151674   ,  28.1688

3      , 2     , -26.151674   ,  28.1688

4      , 2     , -26.151674   ,  28.1688

5      , 3     , -26.151674   ,  28.1688

6      , 3     , -26.151674   ,  28.1688

IMUS_ID, IMUL_ID, DATE_SOS_RAISED, DATE_SOS_CLEARED

1, 1 , 1/29/2021 7:32:54 AM, 1/29/2021 7:32:54 AM

2, 1 , 1/29/2021 7:32:54 AM, (Null)

3, 2 , 1/29/2021 7:32:54 AM,  1/29/2021 7:32:54 AM

4, 2,  1/29/2021 7:32:54 AM, (null)

5, 3,  1/29/2021 7:32:54 AM,  1/29/2021 7:32:54 AM

6, 3,  1/29/2021 7:32:54 AM, (null)

Here is an example of how i want it to be displayed

I_MOBILE_USERS.IMU_NAME, I_MOBILE_USERS.IMU_SURNAME, I_MOBILE_USERS.IMU_CELL_NO, I_MOBILE_USER_LOCATIONS.IMUL_LATITUDE, I_MOBILE_USER_LOCATIONS.IMUL_LONGITUDE

Devin, Gericke, 0123456789,  -26.151674   ,  28.1688

Jan, Koen, 0123456789,  -26.151674   ,  28.1688

Pieter, Du plooy, 0125346789, -26.151674   ,  28.1688

But it should only be displayed when the date_sos_cleared column is null and it should only show one row per person and contain there last know location

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be very helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/

Comment: Thanks for providing the additional information - could you re-format and make it *runnable* code - a "create table" script for each table and insert statements for the data.